# What statistical tests to understand the sensitivity of model output

Tags: regression, variance, multivariate-analysis

I apologies if this post seems very basic but I have no background in statistics.

I have data which represents how a value Y varies based on variables X1,X2 and X3.

The model was ran using as input 3 values for each X (max, min, and modal). All the possible combinations where modelled.

I now have a bunch of data (minus unstable simulations), and I would like to understand how the variation in say X3 affects the output Y. At the moment I am stuck because the only way I can visualise that is by varying X3 whilst keeping all other Xs fixed, which I feel is very limiting and not representative of how sensitive Y is to changes in X3.

I had a look online but it all sounded very cryptic to me. What I got out was that I should maybe look into doing a variance analysis. Any suggestion on where to start would be welcome.

If this helps this is my data:

```
Y            X1     X2  X3
0.098693254 200     40  650
0.098695645 200     40  650
0.986931992 200     350 100
0.986952496 200     350 100
9.890537462 200     174 650
10.18136496 200     40  650
10.41707612 200     350 100
10.46282234 200     350 650
10.53599551 200     174 100
10.65410329 200     174 100
11.10765123 200     350 650
12.33200111 200     174 100
39.60161495 800     40  650
41.94150354 800     40  650
45.41855865 800     40  650
46.01990078 800     40  1330
51.98529614 800     174 100
52.13857696 800     174 100
52.82411159 800     174 100
54.14429892 800     350 100
56.33464844 800     350 100
56.92462061 800     350 650
57.13321811 800     350 100
58.06452441 800     174 650
58.43607908 800     174 1330
58.68248007 800     350 650
59.03229658 800     174 650
59.14210807 800     174 650
59.57596396 800     174 1330
59.65001434 800     350 1330
59.68036781 800     350 650
59.69885109 800     350 1330
59.87127872 800     350 1330
98.69824844 4000    40  650
98.72248575 4000    40  1330
98.72292497 4000    40  100
98.80943542 2750    40  100
98.87854991 4000    40  1330
98.88838986 800     40  100
98.99226373 2750    40  100
98.99543762 4000    40  650
98.99900856 4000    40  650
99.86279486 2750    40  100
100.2009356 4000    40  1330
100.468212  4000    40  100
102.0068472 2750    40  650
103.162789  2750    40  1330
105.6319149 2750    40  1330
110.7793964 2750    40  650
112.6182297 2750    40  1330
113.841467  2750    40  650
143.8822019 2750    350 100
153.4414097 2750    350 100
160.4348542 2750    350 100
162.3443681 2750    350 650
164.1158397 2750    350 650
165.989162  2750    174 100
167.4937763 2750    350 650
167.7102235 2750    350 1330
168.8859242 2750    174 100
169.0078697 2750    174 100
169.5582039 2750    350 1330
170.239271  2750    350 1330
170.649928  2750    174 1330
171.1543206 2750    174 650
171.1778924 2750    174 1330
171.6959122 2750    174 650
173.0006788 2750    174 650
173.7650616 2750    174 1330
182.259278  4000    174 100
188.668617  4000    174 100
189.5339886 4000    350 650
190.350967  4000    174 1330
191.0498577 4000    350 100
191.1190798 4000    174 100
192.1271516 4000    350 100
192.3995197 4000    350 100
193.435914  4000    350 650
194.5565732 4000    174 1330
194.8856331 4000    350 1330
194.9161045 4000    350 650
195.3022703 4000    174 1330
195.5546211 4000    174 650
196.0281905 4000    350 1330
196.4900762 4000    350 1330
198.5173901 4000    174 650
199.5573994 4000    174 650
```

So far I have the following regression results (using some squared variables and log ones to try and capture the non-linearity of the parameters):

```
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                      y   R-squared:                       0.927
Model:                            OLS   Adj. R-squared:                  0.921
Method:                 Least Squares   F-statistic:                     168.1
Date:                Thu, 15 Sep 2016   Prob (F-statistic):           3.30e-43
Time:                        09:21:05   Log-Likelihood:                -374.10
No. Observations:                  87   AIC:                             762.2
Df Residuals:                      80   BIC:                             779.5
Df Model:                           6                                         
Covariance Type:            nonrobust                                         
===================================================================================================
                coef       std err          t      P>|t|      [95.0% Conf. Int.]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
cst            -2.9508      0.334     -8.840      0.000        -3.615    -2.286
X1             0.0888      0.007     13.619      0.000         0.076     0.102
X2             0.8455      0.086      9.813      0.000         0.674     1.017
X3             0.0862      0.021      4.153      0.000         0.045     0.127
X1^2           -1.119e-05   1.47e-06     -7.640      0.000     -1.41e-05 -8.28e-06
X2^2          -0.0016      0.000     -8.117      0.000        -0.002    -0.001
X3^2          -3.916e-05   1.26e-05     -3.097      0.003     -6.43e-05  -1.4e-05
ln(X2)        -9.1129      1.031     -8.836      0.000       -11.165    -7.060
ln(X3)        -12.2176      1.382     -8.840      0.000       -14.968    -9.467
==============================================================================
Omnibus:                       37.314   Durbin-Watson:                   1.332
Prob(Omnibus):                  0.000   Jarque-Bera (JB):              128.220
Skew:                           1.329   Prob(JB):                     1.44e-28
Kurtosis:                       8.320   Cond. No.                     7.44e+22
==============================================================================

Warnings:
[1] Standard Errors assume that the covariance matrix of the errors is correctly specified.
[2] The smallest eigenvalue is 1.49e-30. This might indicate that there are
strong multicollinearity problems or that the design matrix is singular.
```

Comment: This sounds like an Uncertainty Quantification problem. Some more details on the problem would help answering the question. Physically, what are the $X_i$ and $Y$? As you mention simulations, I guess the value of $Y$ is the result from a computer code. If so, what causes $Y$ to assume different values for identical input vectors? Is this due to (pseudo)-randomness in your simulation? What assumption are you making on the joint distribution of the $X_i$? Are they independent? What are their marginal distributions?

Comment: btw, can I ask you what stat tool did you use to generate the regression summary? Just curious.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot name what Xi and Y are. The variation for similar inputs is due to the fact that in reality I have another X parameter (call it X4), however the regression showed a P-value for it which implied it was not statistically significant, hence why I removed it from the regression. I am not sure what you mean by joint distribution but I basically assume that the parameters are totally independent. Say, 40 <= X2 <= 350, and 200 <= X1 <= 4000, then for any value of X2 I can encounter all the values of X1. I assume all values in the range are equally likely.

Comment: For the regression summary I used `statsmodels` in Python. See answer to this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39332102/how-to-output-regression-analysis-summary-from-polynomial-regression-with-scikit

Comment: If I understand correctly, the $X_i$ are continous variables with uniform (marginal) distributions. Is there any particular reason why you didn't perform runs at the mean/median values? E.g., $X_2$ has values {40, 174, 350}, but there are no runs with $X_2 = 195$

Comment: The reason is that I will use the model to get some information on a dataset, I selected the modal value of that dataset as my third value so that I could have actual model runs at those values.

Comment: So far I have done a test using Total-Order indices and First-Order indices. My understanding is that those values will inform me one how much of the variance in my output is due to each parameter.

Comment: If you're still interested in the question, I'll write an answer this week.  In meantime, please include  $X_4$ also in your table.